# Removing leading and trailing spaces from a string while preserving spaces in between

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a string in cell A1 that looks like

```
    abc      123
```

It is a string with several leading spaces, trailing spaces, and spaces in-between.
How can I strip the leading and trailing spaces while preserving the spaces in-between?

The result should be

```
abc      123
```

I have tried using the `TRIM` function as such

```
=TRIM("    abc     123    ")
```

But this is the result I am getting

```
abc 123
```

I am running on Excel 2007, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is the question again? If you need to "get a text value with the leading and trailing spaces removed." then as answers below [TRIM](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) should solve your problem.

Comment: "while preserving the spaces in-between"

Comment: You might find it easiest to create a small UDF using the VBA `Trim()` function (which leaves internal spaces untouched)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this simple UDF.  The VBA version of Trim doesn't remove any internal spaces.

In a regular module:

```
Function VbaTrim(v)
    VbaTrim=Trim(v)
End Function
```

On the worksheet:

```
=VbaTrim(A1)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it is easy to understand if others were to look at my workbook...unless they didn't know anything about UDF's I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend Tim's UDF because there's no simple way to do this with a formula....but for what it's worth this is a formula I have suggested in the past

`=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1)),REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(RIGHT(TRIM(A1)),A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))),1,FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1)),A1)-1,""),"")`

It copes with cells that are blank (returns a blank) and cells that contain only spaces (as those are deemed to be leading/trailing also returns a blank)

Comment: +1. This is an interesting solution, as it's good to see that it can be done without resorting to scripting, but I'd also go with the UDF approach since it is available.